Log resolution and a divisor of pullback of function
Let $(X,x)$ be a three fold singularity
$m_{X,x}$ a ideal sheaf correspoinding to $x$.
$\sigma:Y_1\rightarrow X$ blow up at by $m_{X,x}$
$\phi:Y\rightarrow Y_1$ resolution of $Y_1$
Set $f:=\phi*\sigma$ the composition.
Since $f$ goes throught the blow up, the sheaf $m_{X,x}O_{Y}$ is invertible sheaf and we can wright $m_{X,x}O_{Y}=O_{Y}(\sum_{i=1}^r-s_iE_i)$ where $s_i\geq 0$ and $E_i$ are exceptional divisor of $f$.

My question is as follows.
(i) Are there exists an element $h\in m_{X,x}$ s.t $v_{E_i}(h)=s_i$ for all $i$?
(ii) For general element $h\in m_{X,x}$,$v_{E_i}(h)=s_i$ for all $i$?
Here is what I found.
In Chapters on Algebraic Surfaces Miles Reid 4.6 p84,
https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9602006
He define the fiber cycle $Z_f$ as the greatest divisor in every g, that is
$Z_f=\rm{gcd}(\rm{div}(g)|\forall g\in m_{X,p}\subset O_{X,p})$
In this section, he also says as follows,
"In more geometric terms, take a finite dimensional vector subspace $V\subset O_{X,p}$ which generates $m_{p}$ as a $O_{X,p}$-module, and for $g\in V$ consider the divisor $H_g$, a variable  hyperplane through $P$. Then for fixed $g$, $\rm{div}(g)=f^*(H_g)=L+\sum b_i\Gamma_i$, where $L$ has no components in common with ${\Gamma_i}$ and $\sum b_i\Gamma$ is an effective divisor. If $g\in V$ is "fairly general" then $\sum b_i\Gamma_i$ takes on a certain minimal value, which is $Z_f$"
So he insists what I want to know.
Do you know any proof of the above statement?
